# What is the difference between a tatkal and premium tatkal ticket in Indian Railways?

Tags: tickets, indian-railways, tatkal

What is the difference between a tatkal and premium tatkal ticket in Indian Railways?

I wanted a book a ticket in tatkal but it shows already the tickets are in waiting list. How is that possible?

Also how to know in advance whether a tatkal or a premium tatkal ticket is available for a particular train or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference between Tatkal and Premium Tatkal is that Premium Tatkal is an **Online Only** service.

According to [Times of India](http://m.timesofindia.com/city/patna/Now-Tatkal-tickets-available-at-a-premium/articleshow/44525341.cms)

> Passengers can book premium Tatkal tickets online only on the pattern of airline fares - more the demand, higher the fare.
>
> According to a Railway Board official, premium Tatkal tickets are dynamically priced like air fares. The minimum premium fare is the basic train fare plus Tatkal charges, which vary from 10% to 30% depending on the class of travel, he said, adding the maximum limit for booking premium Tatkal ticket is 30% of the base fare or Rs400, whichever is higher.

Answer (score 4):

The Premium Tatkal (PT) Quota introduced by Railway differs from Tatkal (PT) Quota in the following ways :

- Opening days booking to be allowed on/after 10:00 hrs.
- Advance Reservation Period (ARP) of Premium Tatkal ticket booking is same as Tatkal ticket booking.
- Agents will not be allowed to book tickets in this quota.
- Dynamic fare shall be charged for confirm passengers.
- Dynamic fare stands for the fare component which may be increased    with the subsequent bookings.
- RAC/ Waitlist Ticket Booking is not allowed.
- Only E-tickets will be permitted for booking.
- I-ticket Booking is not allowed with this Quota.
- Child passenger will be charged with full fare.
- Identity card number of the prescribed proof of identity is required at the time of booking. At least one passenger should travel with his/her ID card in original which was used at the time of booking.
- No refund is given to passengers in case of cancellation of confirm PT quota ticket.
- All rules for tatkal quota booking over internet is applicable to Premium Tatkal quota also.

Reference :

1. [Indian Railways](http://services.irctc.co.in/betaDoc/salient%20features%20of%20PT%20quota.pdf).
2. [The Hindu](https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/economy/logistics/With-Premium-Tatkal-Railways-brings-in-dynamic-ticket-pricing/article20880131.ece).